# How to "Modify Auto-Assign Public IP" on subnet with boto?

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto, vpc

How to "Modify Auto-Assign Public IP" on a subnet with boto?

There is an option in the Amazon's web interface which I cannot find in boto..

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## boto3

This is possible with the [EC2.Client.modify_subnet_attribute()](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.modify_subnet_attribute) function.

## boto2

ModifySubnetAttribute was not implemented in boto2. The action was added to the AWS API at a time when development on boto2 had slowed ([2014-06-15](https://web.archive.org/web/20161019214136/https://aws.amazon.com/developertools/351)). There was a GitHub [issue](https://github.com/boto/boto/issues/2646) (now closed) and [pull request](https://github.com/boto/boto/pull/2678) (which may or may not work and is lacking tests). It seems unlikely this will be added.

If you need this functionality and can't use boto3, you could try this:

```
orig_api_version = ec2_conn.APIVersion
ec2_conn.APIVersion = '2014-06-15'
ec2_conn.get_status(
    'ModifySubnetAttribute',
    {'SubnetId': 'subnet-abcd1234', 'MapPublicIpOnLaunch.Value': 'true'},
    verb='POST')
ec2_conn.APIVersion = orig_api_version
```

Answer (score 2):

The API call you're looking for is [ModifySubnetAttribute](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/ApiReference-query-ModifySubnetAttribute.html) but this doesn't seem to be implemented in boto.

(searching for `ModifySubnetAttribute` in the [boto source](https://github.com/boto/boto) doesn't produce any results).